# How to formally show a triangular region in the plane is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions

Consider the region
$$
D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x\ge0, y\ge 0, y<1-x\}.
$$
I know this is the region between the $x$ axis, the $y$ axis and $y=1-x$, where the $x$ and $y$ axis are included in $D$ but $y=1-x$ is not.
How can I formally show that $D$ is bounded? The only definition of boundedness I know is:
$D$ is bounded if there exists $M>0$ such that $D$ is contained in the ball of radius $M$.

Comment: The graph incudes for example the point $(1/2,1/3)$ which is not on the graph of $y=1-x.$ [In fact no points of $y=1-x$ are on your graph, since $y<1-x$ is one of the conditions.]

Comment: @coffeemath sorry, I did not understand, how it is related to the bounded?
but anyway, you gave me an example, my question is, how do I relate it to formal proof with $\epsilon$ and such? like, when I  want to prove the limit of $|an-l|<\epsilon$, I use epsilon, how do I use it here?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "group" and not "set"?

Comment: @Shaun no Idea what is set in english. I know in my laungage, it is called group
from looking at google, it could be set. sorry, I did not learn english math in academics

Comment: when I mean group, is like a team, like the D I wrote above, and such. if its a set, then its my bad. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ball of radius $M$ centered at $0$
$$
B_M=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 \leq M\}.
$$
To see $D$ is bounded it is enough to prove that $D \subseteq B_M$ for some $M>0$. So consider $(x_0, y_0) \in D$, rewriting part of the definition of $D$ we must have
$$x_0+y_0<1.
$$
Since $x_0 \geq 0$ we must have $y_0 <1$ and since $y_0 \geq 0$ we must have $x_0<1$. Therefore $0 \leq x_0 <1$ and $0 \leq y_0 <1$.
Thus
$$x_0^2+y_0^2 < 2,$$
and so $(x_0,y_0) \in B_2$. Since $(x_0,y_0)$ was an arbitrary point in $D$ this means $D \subseteq B_2$, so $D$ is bounded.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, this is exactly the kind of proof I was thinking of, I saw proof of open set ( or open group ) and closed set ( or group ), but there was no proof of bounded set ( or group ), so I could not know how to prove it, unlike the other two. 
Thank you very much!! now I understand how!!

Comment: Sorry, if you saw what I just commented ( not the first one ) - dont mind it , I thought i did not understand something, it was a mistake of mine, I understood all eventually, huge thanks!!

Comment: Hi, can I ask a question? let us say we have the function $x^2+y^2+z^2<1$
How do I show according to the definition that it is bounded?
Because I know it is not bounded by 1, but by two, but the question, how do I show it like you did above? since x,y,z has no boundaries.